# Given n objects shared by several sets of known sizes, what is the minimum number of objects shared by all the sets?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics

Here is what seems to be an easy case.  Suppose there are 13 objects and 3 sets A, B, and C of size 9 sharing those objects.  Set A can have any 9 of the objects.  Set B can have at most 4 objects not in A, so A and B share at least 5 objects.  Set C must share at least 5 objects with A and 5 objects with B. C can only have 9 objects, so it must share at least one of them with both A and B.  Is this reasoning correct?

How can the general case of such a problem be solved?  You know the size of the union of all sets of objects and the sizes of  each set.  How can you determine the minimum size for the intersection of all the sets?

Comment: Another way to organize the argument: the complement of $A$ has at most 4 elements, and similarly for $B$ and $C$; so $A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c$ has at most 12 elements.  Therefore, since $A \cap B \cap C$ has complement with at most 12 elements, $A \cap B \cap C$ has at least 1 element.  (If I'm not mistaken, a similar argument in more general cases should give a tight lower bound for the size of the intersection.)

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine and is completely generalizable.  You can easily determine which objects will be shared.  If A, B and C are respectively missing, 1,2,3,4 and 5,6,7,8 and 9,10,11,12 then 13 is the single object that they all share.

Answer (score 1):

A general approach is to use integer linear programming, with a nonnegative decision variable $x_S$ for each of the nonempty subsets $S$ of the given sets and linear constraints to enforce the cardinalities.  For your example, the problem is to minimize $x_{111}$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_{001} + x_{011} + x_{101} + x_{111} &= 9 \\
x_{010} + x_{011} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 9 \\
x_{100} + x_{101} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 9 \\
x_{001} + x_{010} + x_{011} + x_{100} + x_{101} + x_{110} + x_{111} &= 13 
\end{align}
As you observed, the minimum objective value is $1$, attained by $x_{011}=x_{101}=x_{110}=4$, $x_{111}=1$, and all other $x_S = 0$.

The maximum objective value turns out to be $7$.

Comment: I do not understand what the x values stand for.  Isn't the maximum equal to 9, when the three groups are identical? There are solutions for 8 where the groups are different, for example: A=1-9, B=1-8,10 and C=1-8,11.

Comment: If the three groups are identical with 9 objects, they don’t cover the 13 objects.

Comment: Couldn't we arrive at 7 by solving for:  x + 3(9-x) >= 13?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.